# DataTable with fixed column not looking good

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I tried to make the first column of my data table fixed and I could do it, the first column is static when I use the scroll, the problem is that the header look transparent, so when I scroll to the right I can see the content of the td elements below the first column, although it's working fine for the body of the table.

For example: Hotel is the first column and Total Pasajeros is the second column, when I scroll to the right I'm able to see Total Pasajeros below Hotel, and so on...

[image]

This is the code I've used, what can I do to fix it?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#hoteles').DataTable({
            scrollY: "450px",
            scrollX: true,
            paging: false,
            fixedColumns: {
                leftColumns: 1
            }
        });
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the JS where you are creating your table it is a little hard to gauge.

A couple things come to mind. You might try calling:

```
var table = $('#hoteles').DataTable();    
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

this will recalculate the column layout. 
See: https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()

Another thing you can look at is giving that first column more space to work with. In your table properties you can define columns with classes like this:

```
"columns": [
            { "title": "Hotel", "class": "nowrap", "width": "15%;"},
            { "title": "Total Pasajeros", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Col3", "class": "nowrap", "width": "5%;" },
            { "title": "Col4" },
            { "title": "Col5", "class": "nowrap" }
        ]
```

See: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is the solution I made, first add `.fixed-row` to the container (not the table), and use bootstrap responsive table:

```
function bs_tableAdapter(){
            var tableContainer = $('.fixed-row table');
            var calculateWidth = 0;
            tableContainer.each(function(e,n){
                var clone  = $(n).clone(true);
                var pos = $(n).position();
                var tmp = 0;
                clone.find('th').not(':eq(0)').remove();
                clone.find('tbody tr').each(function(){
                    $(this).find('td').not('.heads').remove();
                });
                clone.addClass('fixed-row-clone');
                $(n).find('tr').each(function(){
                    var elem = $(this).find('.heads').parents('.tab-pane').show().end();
                    calculateWidth = elem.outerWidth() + 10;
                    elem.parents('.tab-pane').css('display','');
                    if(tmp < calculateWidth){
                        tmp = calculateWidth;
                    }
                });

                clone.css({
                    left: pos.left,
                    top: pos.top,
                    width: tmp
                });

                clone.find('th,td').css({
                    'width': tmp+'px',
                    'padding-right' : '0px'
                });
                $('.fixed-row').append(clone);
            });
        }
```